# Setting up nginx as reverse proxy with uwsgi

Tags: nginx, freebsd, reverse-proxy

I am setting up an nginx server to run as a proxy between uwsgi server running my python flask application and outside world. I have set up my uwsgi application to listen on /tmp/myapp.sock and it works correctly.

I'm unable to get nginx to run correctly.
I have this configuration file in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server {
        listen 3120;
        server_name www.mydomain.com;

# www.mydomain.com exists on DNS.
# Since it updates frequently because I do not have a static ip, I cannot set an IP here.
# Plus, I have forwared port 3120 from my router to my RPI3 running.

        location= /myapp {rewrite ^ /myapp/; }
        location /myapp { try_files $uri @myapp; }
        location @myapp {
            include uwsgi_params;
            wsgi_pass unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
            }
    }
```

I use "sudo nginx" to start nginx. The above config file shows no error on config test but my site doesn't turn up online! Please help. I've been trying to get it to work since days.

I use FreeBSD 12.1 on RPi3.

Comment: You might try running nginx with `service nginx start`. The service file often does some additional checking and might aid with debugging.